# My Windows 7 Computer uses the proxy from Spybot Search&Destroy. Does this work ok?

Tags: proxy

Tor Browser options==>Advanced==>Network==>Settings shows a manual setting of SOCKS host: 127.0.0.1 and port 9050.  I have not changed anything within the Tor Browser or the settings for the Spybot proxy, which is the system proxy.  I just want to confirm that all is fine as is.  Or do I need to turn off the Spybot proxy when I use the Tor Browser?

Answer (score 1):

> Tor Browser options==>Advanced==>Network==>Settings shows a manual setting of SOCKS host: 127.0.0.1 and port 9050.  I have not changed anything within the Tor Browser [...]

TOR Browser uses these settings to connect to TOR on the local machine to route traffic through the TOR network and are thus set automatically.

> [D]o I need to turn off the Spybot proxy when I use the Tor Browser?

Unfortunately, I don't use Spybot but if everything is working correctly with the Spybot Proxy enabled, this is probably more a question of privacy.

Introducing a new piece of software enhances the risk of exploits or data leaks in general. TOR operates just fine without a secondary proxy and unless the Spybot proxy is providing VPN services (in which case, there are a ton of articles on TOR/VPN combination) I would be highly tempted to turn it off.